# Drawing currency symbol

Tags: iphone

How to draw a currency symbol in a  custom label using CGContextShowTextAtPoint method in draw rect.
Here the symbol is in string format.

Any help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resort to `C` style strings, since this is what `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()` requires. In order to correctly handle the locale (the currency symbol changes with the locale) you must use `setlocale()`, then you format your string using `strfmon()` and finally you pass the string created with `strfmon(`) to `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()`.

Documentation is available as follows from the terminal:

```
man 3 setlocale
man 3 strfmon
```

EDIT/UPDATE: For your information, `strfmon()` internally uses `struct lconv`. The structure can be retrieved with the function `localeconv()`. See `man 3 localeconv` for a detailed description of the fields available in the structure.

for instance, try the following simple C program setting different locales

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <monetary.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    double val = 1234.567;

    /* use your current locale */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); 

    /* uncomment the next line and try this to use italian locale */
    /* setlocale(LC_ALL, "it_IT"); */ 
    strfmon(buf, sizeof buf, "You owe me %n (%i)\n", val, val);

    fputs(buf, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The following uses `localeconv()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct lconv l;
    int i;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    l = *localeconv();

    printf("decimal_point = [%s]\n", l.decimal_point);
    printf("thousands_sep = [%s]\n", l.thousands_sep);

    for (i = 0; l.grouping[i] != 0 && l.grouping[i] != CHAR_MAX; i++)
        printf("grouping[%d] = [%d]\n", i, l.grouping[i]);

    printf("int_curr_symbol = [%s]\n", l.int_curr_symbol);
    printf("currency_symbol = [%s]\n", l.currency_symbol);
    printf("mon_decimal_point = [%s]\n", l.mon_decimal_point);
    printf("mon_thousands_sep = [%s]\n", l.mon_thousands_sep);
    printf("positive_sign = [%s]\n", l.positive_sign);
    printf("negative_sign = [%s]\n", l.negative_sign);
}
```

Comment: a C style string can also be defined like I did in my answer.
a char pointer is a C string.

Comment: Sure. The problem here is not how to define a C string, rather how to correctly print locale dependent symbols (currency, time etc) inside it. The proposed solution uses the ISO C99 standard functions to deal with currency symbols.

Comment: From above solution i only get currency code of different lacale. I need to get the symbol representing currency of a country.How can i retrieve symbol and put it in showTextAtPoint.

Comment: The examples show how to retrieve both the currency code and symbol. Using the struct lconv the symbol is the field named currency_symbol and the code is the field int_curr_symbol. With strfmon() using %n the double argument is formatted as a national monetary amount printed using the currency symbol, and using %i the double argument is formatted as an international monetary amount using the currency code. This is what the ISO C99 standard provides.

Comment: decimal_point = [,]


thousands_sep = [. ]
int_curr_symbol = [EUR ]
currency_symbol = [Eu]
mon_decimal_point = [,]
mon_thousands_sep = [.]
positive_sign = []
negative_sign = [-]


This is the output i got for locale it_IT.

Comment: I solved the problem in an alternate way. Instead of showTextAtPoint i use drawAtPoint. That solved my problem. Here i get the  currency symbol from  currencySymbol method of NSNuberformatter class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're asking,
checking the documentation, the method would look something like that:

```
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
 const char *string = "$";
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint (ctx, 160, 240, string, 1);
```

Haven't tested it, but this should draw $ in the center of the screen. 
BTW, why not use images?

~ Natanavra.